# D3.js ignores duplicate values

Tags: ajax, d3.js

I'm exploring D3.js. I primarily used their [tutorial](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/tutorial/bar-1.html) to get what I have. But I have made some adjustments.
What I'm doing is counting the number of active & inactive items in a specific table. It then displays a graph with those values. Most everything works fines. I have 2 issues with it though:

1. It doesn't update automatically with my AJAX call when items are deleted. Only updates when items are added. But I'm not concerned about this for this post.
2. My primary issue: duplicate values aren't being treated as individual numbers. Instead it sees [10,10] and outputs it as a single bar in the graph as 10 (instead of 2 bars).

Looking at the D3 docs, it would seem the issue lies with .data. Documentation mentions that it joins data.

```
$(document).on("DOMSubtreeModified DOMNodeRemoved", ".newsfeed", function() {
    var columns = ['created','deleted'];
    var data = [numN, numD];
    var y = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(data)])
            .range([0, 420]);
    var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .domain(columns)
            .rangeBands([0, 120]);
    chart.selectAll("rect")
            .data(data)
 //.enter().append("rect")
            .attr("x", x)
            .attr("height", y)
            .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
            .attr("rx", 10)
            .attr("ry", 10);
    chart.selectAll("text")
            .data(data)
 //.enter().append("text")
            .attr("y", y)
            .attr("x", function(d) {
        return x(d) + x.rangeBand() / 2;
    }) //offset
            .attr("dy", -10) // padding-right
            .attr("dx", ".35em") // vertical-align: middle
            .attr("text-anchor", "end") // text-align: right
            .text(String);
});
```

How can I make each value to display? If I pass in two different values, the chart displays as it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is at `.attr("x", x)`.  So the way you're doing it assigns the same `x` coordinate for both `rect`s.

So try offsetting `x` coordinate.

```
.attr("x", function(d, i) { x + i * width_of_your_rect); })
```

Comment: Great! Thanks icanc. That is pretty close to what I needed. The proper syntax that works for me is: `.attr("x", function(d,i) {return  i * x.rangeBand(); })`  And then to make sure my labels get added correctly as well, I had to change my text offset to: `.attr("x", function(d,i) {return (i * x.rangeBand()) + (x.rangeBand() / 2);})`